# MPMoviePlayerViewController and UIWebView HTML5 video

Tags: ios, html, video, uiwebview, mpmovieplayer

I am having some trouble with an iOS project wherein I have an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` playing a local `.mov` file and also a `UIWebView` which is to be playing another local video file.

It seems that whenever I click the video start button in the `UIWebView`, the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` stops playback. I am getting the `NSNotification` of `MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded` the same as if the movie player reached the end by playing all the way through.

It was my understanding that it is no longer possible to autoplay video in a `UIWebView` but I get this same thing happening if I add autoplay="auto play" to the html file. As an aside, will this work to auto play the video if I solve the other problem? It seems that it will as I am seeing the same thing happen as when I click the video without auto play enabled.

This happens both when the UIWebView is added to the parent view that it shares with the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and when it is added as a child of the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. My goal is to have the `UIWebView` HTML5 video playing as an overlay to the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` video.

Targeting iOS7, using Xcode 5.02.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you will have to use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html) and create your own view controller to achieve this. From [`MPMoviePlayerController`'s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:

> Note: Although you can create multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` objects
>   and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a
>   time can play its movie.

And I think this is why your video gets terminated. `MPMoviePlayerController` basically stops playing when other video session is about to start. Solution for this is to create a custom player view controller using `AVPlayer`. [Here](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/) is how to achieve this.

Comment: There is just one MPMoviePlayerViewController though. Isn't there? The second video is HTML5 video playing in a UIWebView. That isn't an MPMoviePlayerController as I understood it. Am I incorrect on this?

Comment: I suppose that MPMoviePlayerController can only play a video when other video session is not started. That's my interpretation of this behavior. It's not written in the docs though.